# Branch vs Texture Read

Tags: directx, direct3d, hlsl

In shaders, which one is **usually** cheaper, branching (if, etc) or a texture read?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Texture read, **usually**. Branches are typically prohibitively expensive. Of course, so are anisotropic texture reads from extremely large textures that don't have mip-maps, so you need to profile it accordingly.

Btw, you can also use the [predicated] directive in some instances.

EDIT: I should mention the obvious - in your output, look at the numbers to see if you're sequencer-bound or texture-bound.